# convert formatted currency amount to a double value using regex

Tags: javascript

I have different currency format that I want to convert into a double value. Example:

1. 1,000,000.00 => 1000000.00
2. 2'345',00 => 2345.00
3. 2'344'334.03 => 1000000.03

   I have the following solution which works and is very inefficient.I am trying to figure out some regex way of doing it.

   ```
       decimalPlace = amount[amount.length - 3];

   if (decimalPlace === '.' && amount.indexOf(',') < -1 && amount.indexOf("'") < -1) {
       return amount
   }
   if (decimalPlace === ',' && amount.indexOf("'") < -1) {
       value = amount.split('.').join('')
           .replace(',', '.')
       return value
   }
   if (decimalPlace === '.' && amount.indexOf(',') > -1) {
       value = amount.split(',').join('')
       return value
   }

   if (decimalPlace === ',' && amount.indexOf("'") > -1) {
       value = amount.split("'").join('')
           .replace(',', '.')
       return value
   }
   if (decimalPlace === '.' && amount.indexOf("'") > -1) {
       value = amount.split("'").join('')
       return value
   }
   return amount
   ```

I would appreciate any suggestion with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably made this more complicated then it has to be.
If those are the only formats that need to be supported, you could use a function like this:

```js
var v1 = "1,000,000.00";
var v2 = "2'345',00";
var v3 = "2'344'334.03";
var v4 = "2,00"

function format(str){
    if(str.replace(/[^,]/g, "").length === 1){ // Contains only one comma.
        str = str.replace(",", ".");
    }
    if(str.indexOf("'")!=-1){
       str = str.replace(/'/g, "").replace(",", ".");
    }
    return parseFloat(str.replace(/,/g, "")).toFixed(2);
}

[v1, v2, v3, v4].forEach(v => console.log(format(v)));
```

EDIT: I've added support for values with only one comma.

EDIT 2: Actually, it seems that I've made that mistake myself (making thing complicated).

I think all this can be as simple as:

```js
var v1 = "1,000,000.00";
var v2 = "2'345',00";
var v3 = "2'344'334.03";
var v4 = "2,00"

function format(str){
    if(str.replace(/[^,]/g, "").length === 1){ // Contains only one comma.
        str = str.replace(",", ".");
    }
    return parseFloat(str.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, "")).toFixed(2);
}

[v1, v2, v3, v4].forEach(v => console.log(format(v)));
```

Comment: This doesn't pass for 2,00 but I got the idea. I made it complicated just to avoid any edge cases. Let me test some more examples with the function you created.

Comment: @singha4086 `2,00` isn't one of the formats you've mentioned, this function supports only those formats.

Comment: I should have been more clear with the question. Your solution did help me understand the concept though. Thank you  :)

Comment: @singha4086 I've edited my answer to added support for `2,00`.

Comment: @singha4086 I'm glad I could help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend against relying too much on regular expressions here. The way I'd approach this is in 2 parts.

First, work out what the decimal point is. This will change based on locale but it's very easy to work it out - just create a function which will add a localised decimal point and then return it.

```
function getDecimalPoint(locale) {
    return (1.2).toLocaleString(locale).replace(/\d+/g, "");
}
```

The benefit of this function is that if you pass in no `locale`, the current one will be used (which is "en-GB" for me).

Now that you can identify a decimal point, you can use that to split the formatted number into 2 parts - evenything before the decimal (whole numbers) and everything after it (decimals).

```
function unformatNumber(number, locale) {

    // Split the number based on the decimal point.
    var numberParts = String(number).split(getDecimalPoint(locale));

    // Remove everything that isn't a number from the whole numbers and parse
    // it as a number.
    var unformatted = Number(numberParts[0].replace(/\D+/g, ""));

    // Check to see if there are any decimals. If there are, convert them into
    // a decimal and add them to the unformatted result.
    var decimals = numberParts[1];

    if (decimals && decimals.length) {
        unformatted += decimals / Math.pow(10, decimals.length);
    }

    return unformatted;

}
```

To use it, simply pass your numbers to the function.

```
unformatNumber("1,000,000.00"); // -> 1000000
unformatNumber("2'345',00", "fr"); // -> 2345
unformatNumber("2'344'334.03"); // -> 2344344.03
// I know those numbers aren't formatted in French, but you can change your
// format as necessary.
```

```js
function getDecimalPoint(locale) {
    return (1.2).toLocaleString(locale).replace(/\d+/g, "");
}

function unformatNumber(number, locale) {

    var numberParts = String(number).split(getDecimalPoint(locale));
    var unformatted = Number(numberParts[0].replace(/\D+/g, ""));
    var decimals = numberParts[1];

    if (decimals && decimals.length) {
        unformatted += decimals / Math.pow(10, decimals.length);
    }

    return unformatted;
    
}

console.log(unformatNumber("1,000,000.00"));
console.log(unformatNumber("2'345',00", "fr"));
console.log(unformatNumber("2'344'334.03"));
```

Comment: This is a great approach. It some how fails for  2'345'04,01 or any decimal number after ','. It also removes value after the decimal separator.